# How to target variable until hyphen in RegEx if used in a javascript mongoose find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongoose

I'm trying to find all products in JavaScript with Mongoose .find that are identical to another array before the hyphen.

For example: sku in database 10043, sku in array 10043-2.

I'm trying to solve this via Regex, but I'm just stuck here.

I'd really appreciate any help on how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.reports[0].data.rows.length; i++) {
 Product.find({ sku: { $regex:data.reports[0].data.rows[i].dimensions[0], \- } })
          .then((results) => {
            console.log(results)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
}
```

Mongoose Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    pid: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    sku: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salesPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    sourcePrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    permalink: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

module.exports = Product;
```

[Link to JSBin Mongoose Model](https://jsbin.com/mifuhipoce/edit?html,js)

Comment: Hi, it would be more helpful if you can share an example of the document and model.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have added the link above. I just need to find all the entries in the database that match the array entries before the hyphen.

Comment: try this `db.products.find( { sku: { $regex: /10043$/ } } )`

Comment: I get this error when I try your code. CastError: Cast to number failed for value "/10043$/" (type RegExp) at path "sku" for model "Product".